# Using htaccess to rewrite url with variables?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Using htaccess how can instead of the following to have something like

```
http://domain.com/verify
```

or

```
http://domain.com/verify?user=_FIRST-VARIABLE_&verification_code=_SECOND-VARIABLE_
```

Here is the original

```
http://domain.com/account/index.php?user=_FIRST-VARIABLE_&verification_code=_SECOND-VARIABLE_
```

My current htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^login$ account/index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^register$ account/index.php?register [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Post you current RewriteRule/.htaccess file

Comment: @AmitThakur I have just updated my question, thank you

Comment: @AmitThakur yes, tt is located in the root folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this RewriteRule with the regex pattern

```
  RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^varify/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$/account/index.php?foo=$1&bar=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

> change the variables foo and bar with your variables.

All requests to example.com/varify/var1/var2 will be redirected to example.com/account/index.php?foo=$1&bar=$2

Comment: Thank you but when I enter the url `http://domain.com/verify/dfdsds/fdtghtf` I get `/verify/dfdsds/fdtghtf.php was not found on this server.`

Comment: and the `/verify/dfdsds/fdtghtf/` to `/verify/dfdsds/fdtghtf/.php was not found`

Comment: check your links, does the index.php exist?